# ¿Cuando es necesario un puntero en un return de una funcion operator?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy estudiando para un termino y quiero saber cuando utilisamos el return de las funciones operator.

¿Por ejemplo, porque esta necesario el puntero en el `return !((*this)==v);`?

```
class vecteur3d
{    float x;
     public :
     vecteur3d(floatx=0.0)
     {
        x=c1;
     }
     int operator!=(vecteur3d);
};

int vecteur3d::operator !=(vecteur3d v)
{
    return !((*this)==v);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int vecteur3d::operator !=(vecteur3d v)
{
    return !((*this)==v);
}
```

La propia función te dice que va a devolver un entero, luego no, la función no va retornar un puntero sino simplemente un entero. Lo que habría que preguntarse aquí es qué sentido tiene que este operador devuelva un entero en vez de un booleano, que sería lo natural.

¿Qué hace ese `return`?

```
return !((*this)==v);
//        ^^^^^
```

El operador asterisco `*` se usa en este caso para desreferenciar el puntero, es decir, es una forma de acceder al contenido gestionado por el puntero:

```
int* ptr = new int(10);
int var = *ptr; // var = 10
std::cout << var;
```

Seguimos...

```
return !((*this)==v);
//              ^^
```

Ya hemos visto que con el operador `*` estamos accediendo al objeto apuntado, que en este caso es de tipo `vecteur3d`. El operador de comparación está comparando este objeto con `v`, que también es de tipo `vecteur3d`. El resultado de la comparación será un booleano.

```
return !((*this)==v);
//     ^
```

Este último operador va a invertir el valor devuelto por la comparación anterior. Si resulta que `*this` es igual a `v` el operador de comparación devolverá `true` y este operador lo convertirá en `false` y viceversa.

Si despiezamos la línea de código se ve mejor la secuencia de instrucciones:

```
int vecteur3d::operator !=(vecteur3d v)
{
  vecteur3d yo = *this;
  bool iguales = (yo==v);
  return !iguales;
}
```

En resumen. Esta es una forma sencilla de implementar el operador "distinto de" sin tener que repetir la lógica implementada en el operador de comparación.

Answer (score 3):

> ¿Por ejemplo, porque esta necesario el puntero en el `return !((*this)==v);`?

Ojo, no estás devolviendo el puntero, estás des-referenciandolo. Anteponer el asterisco (`*`) a un dato de tipo puntero nos devuelve una referencia al dato apuntado, así que podríamos desglosar toda la instrucción de la siguiente manera:

```
int vecteur3d::operator !=(vecteur3d v)
{
    vecteur3d &referencia = *this;
    bool comparacion = (referencia == v);

    return !comparacion;
}
```

Como ves, no es estrictamente necesario hacerlo todo en una línea, pero es bastante claro cuando sabes lo que significa. En este caso, se está des-referenciando el puntero `this` para acceder al operador `==` (que no veo declarado en la clase `vecteur3d`), otra manera de escribir esta instrucción sería:

```
int vecteur3d::operator !=(vecteur3d v)
{
    return !this->operator ==(v);
}
```

Es una práctica común el escribir operadores en base al operador opuesto (por ejemplo `<` en base a `>`, `==` en base a `!=`) para evitar duplicar código y facilitar el mantenimiento.